# Create clickable row table in VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm a beginner in VueJS ... and I have the following scenario: I have a web webapp created in LARAVEL / API and VUEJS / CLIENT, I have a table with a list of expenses, I would like to be able to click on each expense twice to be able to view that expense.
I know I will have to pick up keyboard events, but not how to implement this on my WebApp ... can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table row using TR element, simply do `<tr @dblclick="showDetail(item)">` or if it is a DIV, then do `<div @dblclick="showDetail(item)">`

Then on your object methods, create showDetail function

Item refers to the object being rendered on row

```
methods: {
    showDetail (item) {
    }
},
```

Comment: thanks for answering friend. So this event @dblclick and vuejs? why I couldn't find it in the vue doc. I also wanted to browse the list using only the UP and DOWN keys. I want to implement a checkbox to be marked too.

Comment: Well, change, blur, and some other event also not in vue.js doc, but those functionalities do exists. Most of the primitive event that exists on traditional javascript are adopted by vue. Following link example for dblclick https://codepen.io/robertourias/pen/LxVNZX